# How to make local master a remote branch with git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I started out by cloning a repository (git clone https://blahblah_repository). I then made some changes and did a commit. I did not branch first but I now want to push to a branch that does not yet exist.

1. How do I create a branch on the server and then push my non-branched local commit to the new branch assuming that the master head has not moved since I cloned it?
2. If the master head did move since cloning, how would I branch off the previous master commit on the server and then push my changes there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are currently in master with additional commit.

First of all checkout to new branch

`git checkout -b new_branch`

The `new_branch` will have the additional commit you have done in the master branch

Push the new branch to server (e.g github). It will create new branch to server automatically if no branch of this name exist.

`git push origin new_branch`

After succesful push, Now checkout to master branch

`git checkout master`

Now remove extra top most commit from master

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

---

If you have already pushed additional commit in master branch then after reset do force push

`git push origin master -f`.

it will make remote master even with local master

cheers!!

Comment: One may need to use `git push -u origin new_branch`, depending on one's `push.default` setting and Git version.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. It appears that my questions were one and the same though. It automatically branches off the original cloned position if the master moved on. I'm not quite sure what your last two commands do though. I imagine the git reset --hard HEAD~1 is refreshing the local without concern for conflicts to be the master head once again. But then why is it pushing after?

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

1.You mean you committed your local changes on local master branch, but now you want to make the changes on another branch and create the same branch on git server. You can use below steps:

```
git branch branchname
git reset --hard origin/master
git push -u origin branchname
```

2.For the situation, you want to rebase your local master change on the top of master, and then push the local master changes to remote. You can use below steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master --rebase
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question comes in two parts:

> 1. How do I create a branch on the server and then push my non-branched local commit to the new branch assuming that the master head has not moved since I cloned it?
> 2. If the master head did move since cloning, how would I branch off the previous master commit on the server and then push my changes there?

but in fact, it reveals the usual confusion everyone has with Git, which is the difference between branch and branch—or maybe, branch, branch, and branch.  Git uses one *word* to mean at least two different things.  (After which, the distributed nature of Git complicates the complications.)

#### What *is* a branch anyway?

Let's take on question 1 first and identify the different things we might mean by "branch".  We can use the phrase *branch name* for one of them.  A name like `master` is a *branch name*, and a branch name points to one specific commit.

We have not really defined *commit* yet either, but you have a pretty good idea what commits are about, by this point.  Just in case, though, let's firm it up.  A *commit* is a Git object that:

- represents a snapshot of the source;
- carries an *author* name-email-timestamp, to remember who wrote the code that went into it; and the same for a possible second person, the *committer*, though these days the two are most often the same;
- carries a *log message*; and
- identifies some *parent* commit(s).

This last bit is critical and we'll come back to it in the next paragraph.  For now, let's note that each commit has its own unique hash ID, `8e2df81...` or `ac0ffee...` or `badbead...` or some such.  A *branch name* like `master` is a *human readable name* for one—and *only* one, or rather, one at a time—of these hash IDs.  We call this the *branch tip*, or the *tip commit of the branch*, but this last phrase is a bit unsatisfying: if `master` *is* the branch, how can `master` be the *name* of the *tip* of the branch?  What is the actual branch, then?

Let's imagine a repository with just a few commits in it.  Let's start with just three, and instead of big ugly hash IDs, let's use single-letter names for writing them down.  The first commit we ever make is commit `A`.  Because it *is* the first commit, it cannot have a parent commit.  There's a special name for this parentless commit: it's called a *root* commit.

Now we make a second commit and call it `B`, storing `A`'s actual hash ID in it as its parent.  We say that `B` *points to* `A`.  We make `C` with parent `B` and say that `C` *points to* `B`.  To keep track of it all, we make the name `master` point to C.  Let's *draw* this:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

All of Git's internal arrows are backwards like this—the name `master` finds the *last* commit, which finds an earlier commit, and so on—but it's too much of a pain to draw this way (at least in text on StackOverflow), so let's just use connecting lines from now on:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

To add a *new* commit, we compute its hash ID (really some big ugly hash, but we'll just call it `D`) from its contents: the snapshot, the author and committer, the log message, and its *parent ID* `C`.  We write this commit into the repository database:

```
A--B--C     <-- master
       \
        D
```

and then we *move* the name `master` to point to the new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C     [C used to be master]
       \
        D   <-- master
```

This is how branches grow, by adding *new* commits—this never touches any existing commit at all—and then changing a *branch name* to point to the new *branch tip*.  So the other necessary meaning for branch, whatever other name we might give it—I've suggested the name "DAGlet"; see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)—is *some subset of the commits found by starting at the branch tip and working backwards towards the root*.

This is where the initial confusing bits come in, because Git keeps just using one word for all of these things: a DAGlet like `A-B-C-D` is "a branch", the *tip* commit `D` of branch `master` is "a branch", and `master` itself is "a branch".  But they are all different things.  Git just expects us to know which thing we mean—and after a bit of practice, you really do just know, at least most of the time, but it's nice to have the words *branch name*, *branch tip*, and *DAGlet* when we need to separate them.

#### Creating new branch names and dealing with different repositories

So, now we can look closer at the first *half* of the first question: you need to create a branch *name* on the server.  We can also look at second question at the same time: you may want to create a branch *name* in your own repository.

Git, being Git, offers *two* standard user-interface ways to create branch names *in your own repository:* `git branch` and `git checkout -b`.  We already saw that a branch name just points to one specific commit.  You made a new commit `D` and Git made your own `master` point to this new `D`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- master
```

I drew `D` on its own line originally because I wanted to leave room for the note I had on `C`.  Let's leave that space around to add more names pointing to `C`, and just for the heck of it, let's make a new name, `old-master`, pointing to `C` now.  The way we do that is with `git branch`:

```
git branch old-master <hash-ID-of-commit-C>
```

which results in this:

```
A--B--C     <-- old-master
       \
        D   <-- master
```

Remember, though, this is all happening in *your* repository, with *your* branch names.  There's another Git out there, with another repository, on the server.  *That* Git still only has `A-B-C`, and his `master` still points to `C`.  Here's where Git gets clever: *your* Git remembers, for you, where *his* Git had *his* names, using names exclusive to your repository.  These names are your *remote-tracking branch names*.  (Oh look, another kind of branch!)

Remote-tracking branch names are prefixed with the name of the remote, which is usually `origin`.  So `origin/master` is how *your* Git remembers, for you, that *their* Git has their `master` pointing to commit `C`.  Let's draw that in:

```
A--B--C     <-- old-master, origin/master
       \
        D   <-- master
```

Note that we don't tell our Git to make the `origin/master` name: it does that on its own, by finding *their* `master` and adding `origin/` in front for us.  When we connect our Git to their Git, our Git can get any updates from them and move the `origin/*` names around as needed.  This is what remote-tracking branches are all about: they remember some other Git's name-to-hash-ID mappings for you.

Note also that all of this faffing-about with names has, up until now, the simple goal of *identifying one specific commit*.  If we want a *branch tip*, once we find the commit, we're done.  If we want a *DAGlet*—some set of commits found by working backwards through parent IDs—we're pretty good here too, because the tip commit has the parent ID, and that parent has another parent ID, and so on.  (We might need to tell Git *when to stop going backwards,* but I'll leave that for other SO postings.)

But, now we need to tell our Git to ask that other Git to make a new branch name.  With *our* Git we used `git branch` or (not yet shown here) `git checkout -b`, but that doesn't tell *their* Git anything.  Aside from actually logging in on the server—which would work!—we need a way to have our Git call up their Git and ask it—the server—to do this; and the way we do that is with `git push`.

When we run `git push`, we give it:

- the name of a remote, like `origin`: look up a URL and use that to call up another Git on the Internet-phone, and
- some set of *refspecs*.

Oversimplifying a lot, the *refspecs* are basically *branch names*, but paired with a colon between them:

```
git push origin master:blah
```

The name on the left is *our* name, and the name on the right, `blah`, is the name we would like *their* Git to update, or re-set, or create.  Our Git calls up their Git, has a little conversation to find out what commit(s) we need to send them—ones we have that they don't, like our new commit `D`<sup>1</sup>—and asks them to set *their* name.  If we don't use the `:blah` part, our Git uses *our* name: "Please set your `master` the same way I have my `master` set, to point to this new commit `D` I give you."

---

<sup>1</sup>The way Git figures this out is to do those DAGlet actions.  If we'd added `D` and `E` and `F`, our Git would work back from `F` to `E` to `D` to `C`.  On reaching `C`, their Git would say: "stop, I have that one!" and our Git would send over the `D-E-F` chain.

---

#### But wait, there's more!  Or is it less?!

We can now completely answer question 1, which is also the complete answer to question 2!  Let's say we want to give the server our new commit `D` and have them set a *new* branch name, `test`:

```
git push origin master:test
```

This sends them commit `D` and then ask them to set their `test`, which is new to them, to point to `D`.  Their `master` probably still points to `C`, so *they* get this:

```
A--B--C     <-- master
       \
        D   <-- test
```

Our `git push` transfers the DAGlet first, then asks them to set a name, and we didn't ask them to set their `master`.  So suppose that *their* master *did* move, as in your question 2.  They have:

```
A--B--C--E   <-- master
```

to start with.  We send them `D`, our new commit—remember, every commit has its own magically unique<sup>2</sup> hash ID, so our `D` has a number that's different from their `E`—and ask them to set the branch name `test`, which gives them:

```
A--B--C--E   <-- master
       \
        D    <-- test
```

---

<sup>2</sup>The magic lies in using a good hash function.  Git currently uses SHA-1, which *was* good enough, but now ... well, it's still good enough, but [getting a bit creaky](https://shattered.it/).

---

#### But this leaves us with a bit of a problem of our own

That one `git push` command does the whole job for the *server*, but it leaves *our* repository all messy.  I'm going to drop the name `old-master` since we have `origin/master`.

```
A--B--C     <-- origin/master
       \
        D   <-- master, origin/test
```

We probably don't want this: we'd like to have our own `test` too, to match this new `origin/test` our Git just created to remember *their* `test`.  So now we can use `git checkout -b`, or `git branch`, or a bit of special Git magic with plain old `git checkout`:

```
git checkout test
```

Note that we *don't have a branch named test*, or at least, not yet.  This checkout command is about to fail!  But just before it does, Git says to itself:<sup>3</sup> *Wait, maybe you meant to make a new branch based on an `origin` branch!*  It checks around, and sure enough, there's an `origin/test` now,<sup>4</sup> so it makes a new `test` pointing to the same branch-tip commit, and as a side effect, sets the new branch's *upstream* to `origin/test`:

```
A--B--C     <-- origin/master
       \
        D   <-- master, test, origin/test
```

Now we just need to fix up `master` to point back to commit `C`, like it does<sup>5</sup> on the server.  Git being Git, there are multiple ways to do *that* too, but the one for beginners to use is `git reset --hard`, which is a bit unfortunate as `git reset --hard` is a little bit dangerous, *and* requires that you first switch back *to* branch `master`:

```
git checkout master && git reset --hard origin/master
```

This first puts your Git `on branch master`, as `git status` will say, and then changes the *current* branch—the one you're `on branch`—to point to the same commit as `origin/master`:

```
A--B--C     <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
       \
        D   <-- test, origin/test
```

Note that I added this `(HEAD)` to the drawing: that's to remember which branch we're on.  Now that there are two, `master` and `test`, we always need to know which one is going to get *moved* by `git commit` and `git reset` and so on.

I've completely skipped `git checkout -b` here, but what it does is combine `git branch` with `git checkout`.  It creates a new branch name, like `git branch` would; and it switches to that new branch, like `git checkout` would.  If anything goes wrong in all of this process, it magically manages to *skip* creating the new branch name.  Internally, it does this by "cheating": it does the commit-level checkout step first.  If that succeeds, *now* it creates the branch name and changes which branch you're on.  When you do this manually you're forced to do it in the more sensible order: give the commit a name first, then check out the name-that-names-the-branch-tip.

You can mix these various steps up into various other orders, and if you remember to make a new branch *first*, `git checkout -b` is the way to go.  But the key to keeping all of this straight is to remember that it's the *graph*—the "DAG", made by drawing commits and their parents—that's the permanent part of the equation, while the *branch names* like `master` and `test` are just labels that you can shuffle around all you like.  You need the names to *find* the commits, because the hash IDs are too unwieldy.

---

<sup>3</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers; they hate that.

<sup>4</sup>This assumes your Git is version 1.8.4 or higher.

<sup>5</sup>Or does it?  What if there's that `E` commit?  See the next section.

---

#### Picking up that new commit `E`

Going back to question 2:

> If the master head did move since cloning, how would I branch off the previous master commit on the server and then push my changes there?

we already saw that you don't *have* to pick up the new commit `E` at all, to get your own new commit `D` put onto a new side-branch.  But you might want to see commit `E`.

You can do this *at any time* by running `git fetch`.  Git's `fetch`—**not** `git pull`; I recommend avoiding `git pull`—is as close as Git gets to the opposite of `push`.  Like `git push`, it takes the name of a remote, and some optional set of refspecs, but usually you just name the remote, or let Git figure it out for you since there's probably only one remote anyway:

```
git fetch
```

This calls up the other Git (using the URL from the remote as usual) on the Internet-phone, but this time, instead of your Git sending their Git *your* commits, your Git has their Git send you *their* commits.  Just as before, your Git stops them as soon as they reach the DAGlets you already have, so this only gets *new* commits (well, plus any other data needed to complete those new commits).  Then your Git remembers their branch names by updating all your remote-tracking branch names.  So, if they *do* have commit `E` and you run `git fetch`, your graph goes from:

```
A--B--C     <-- origin/master
       \
        D   [whatever name(s) you have here at this point]
```

to:

```
A--B--C--E     <-- origin/master
       \
        D     [whatever]
```

It's *always safe* to run `git fetch`, because `git fetch` only *adds new commits* to your repository.  It does not—*can* not—change any old ones: the hash ID of a commit is a cryptographic checksum of its contents, so any attempt to *change anything* results in a new, different hash ID.  Instead, it adds any new commits that have appeared, then changes your `origin/*` names to match what's in the other Git.

(I will note, as an aside here, that `git push` can see that their `origin/master` points to commit `E`, but it doesn't change your `origin/master`.  The reason is that `git push` is *sending* things, not *receiving* them.  It *will* update or create remote-tracking branch names for branch-name create-or-updates that you send to them *and* that they then accept, but it won't update any others.  This is a design choice made for a bunch of reasons, including the fact that Git won't let you set a name to point to a commit you don't have.  If you don't have their `E` yet, you can't set your own `origin/master` to point to it.)